# Disciplining one's mouth

Tags: sources-mekorot, words

Where do the words: כל רגע ורגע שאדם חוסם את פיו, זוכה לאור הגנוז שאין כל מלאך ובריה יכולים לשער, originate from?

Comment: Have you looked anywhere? Have you tried to Google it?

Comment: where did you come across those words that would cause you to think they originate somewhere?

Comment: @yEz to be fair it is a song...MBD

Comment: @Mefaresh B"H I don't know of such things

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A cursory google search reveals that the [Chafetz Chaim](http://netsor.org/halachot/56) (Lashon Harah Klal 1:Seif 7) that it is a Maamer Chazal:

> ועל זה שייך מאמר חז"ל "כל רגע ורגע שאדם חוסם את פיו, זוכה לאור הגנוז
>   שאין כל מלאך ובריה יכולים לשער"

However, In Iggeres HaGr"a it is [this maamer is first found](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%90%D7%92%D7%A8%D7%AA_%D7%94%D7%92%D7%A8%22%D7%90). :

> וכל רגע ורגע שהאדם חוסם פיו זוכה בשבילו לאור הגנוז שאין מלאך ובריה
>   יכולים לשער

And it seems to be that in other places i have seen, this maamer is quoted in the name of the Vilna Gaon referencing the Iggeres Hagr"a:

> בדורות האחרונים, נדרש לענייני לשון הרע הגאון ר' אליהו מוילנא (ליטא,
>   המאה הי"ח) באיגרתו הנודעת ("איגרת הגר"א"). לפי דבריו, לשון הרע הוא
>   "החמוּר מכל העבירות", ולכן: "כל רגע ורגע שהאדם חוסם פיו, זוכה בשבילו
>   לאור הגנוז, שאין מלאך ובריה יכולים לשער... כי הפה קדש קדשים

Comment: Which medrash is it in and where in the medrash can it be found?

Comment: doesnt say. seems to be the invention of the Gr"a.

Comment: Yes, this is famously one of those never-found Midrashim.